# Replicating WAS components without redoing

Tags: websphere

I have set of JVM configured, WAS components (Queues, SIB, etc) created in one environment (WAS 8.0 ) and is all working fine. I need to replicate the same in another set of new servers (and another one potentially). How do I replicate all the steps without typing the information again?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you'd make the original changes via scripting and re-run them. An alternative is "properties based configuration" for export/import.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0904_chang/0904_chang.html